# apt-get hangs when trying to install Passenger on new Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: azure, phusion-passenger

I setup a completely new Azure Ubuntu 14.04 server.

After following the instructions here:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu

On step:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this output:

```
Hit http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en      
Hit http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US  
Ign http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty InRelease                 
Ign https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty Release
100% [Working]
```

I waiting for 30mins to no avail.  Tried rebooting and retried doing apt-get update but still the same.

I think this guy is having the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/576546/ubuntu-updating-stopped-while-processing-apt-get-update  answer didn't do anything though.

Answer (score 0):

Got this after 25min.

```
W: Failed to fetch https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Retried now and no problem so probably just site that was down.